# I can't drag Cinema 4D models from the Project Window into the Scene View

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't drag cinema 4d models from the Project View into the Scene View.

[It looks like this in Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZUTB.png)

Another question: can I create models in Unity like Cinema 4D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.c4d` format will not work if you don't have `Cinema 4D` installed.

You can use `.fbx` or `.obj` with any additional software installed in your system.

But if you want to use direct Maya, Blender or other native format, you will need the software installed in your system.

Unity is not a 3D modeling software. So you can't create model in Unity. There are some plugins that just allow modifying model vertices data in editor.

Comment: I have Cinema 4D R14.0.0.41 in my computer ..... I change my files to .fbx or .obj but its same problem ...

Comment: If you could export to fbx or obj properly without internal error, models should be working fine when drag and drop in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what SP. just said.

Please take a look here for all the model formats Unity accepts :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html

And here on how to import Cinema 4D files :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectCinema4D.html

As stated at the bottom of the page, Unity can't use .c4d files directly, it simply uses the Cinema4D application behind the scenes to convert it to a fbx file.
It is also said that Cinema4D's fbx exporter is very unreliable. So I suggest you to take that into account for the future.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has problem with installing c4d unity plugin because of required administrator permission, you can fix it by this scenario :

1. For this to work, Unity Hub also has to run as Administrator.
     Go to the Installation folder of UnityHub and open properties (Alt + Enter) of 
   UnityHub.exe
2. Open the "Compatibility" tab, there you will find a checkbox Run as administrator

Now we can do the same for Unity.

3. Go to the "Editor" folder of the Unity installation you want to run as administrator.
4. Set Administrator settings for Unity.exe (see instructions above)
5. Fully exit Unity and Unity Hub
6. Restart Unity Hub, you should see the Windows dialogue for "Run as administrator"
7. Open a project using the Unity version you customized and Unity will have Admin permissions.
8. If you have problem with dropping objects to Unity, it happens when unity is running as admin, you can just copy and past your files directly using explorer instead of direct dropping.